# Company name translation with LTD

Tags: translation

I know that Company name should not be translated, but LTD or Ltd. should be translated? 
Just for example, Apple Ltd.

Comment: "Ltd.", "Inc", "LLC", "S.A." etc. are part of a company's official business name, and therefore should not be translated.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an odd question for ELL. "Ltd." is already English ("Limited"), so it doesn't need translation.

However, in a more general case, if the company is incorporated in a particular country, then you should use the incorporation designation from that country, untranslated.  For example, there is a large international bank headquartered in Spain that is referred to as **Banco Santander, S.A.** in [English-language articles](https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=323930), even though "S.A." stands for the Spanish phrase "Sociedad Anónima."

This is, however, confused by the fact that multinational companies often have wholly-owned subsidiaries that are locally incorporated.  There is an entity headquartered in Boston that is called **Santander Bank, N.A.** (where "N.A." stands for "National Association").  It is the wholly-owned subsidiary of Banco Santander, S.A. that conducts the parent company's business within the United States.

Comment: Agreed.  I've dealt with a lot of international business, and in legal and formal documents, you always retain the original company type.  A "limited" company in Europe will not be accountable to the same laws and regulations as a "limited liability company" in the US, even though they might have a very similar structure and be treated similarly in their respective countries.